# Почему не получается использовать шрифт?

Tags: java, swing

Скачал шрифт - `19138.ttf`

Скопировал в папку программы. Не могу понять, почему этот код не может загрузить шрифт?

```java
File fontFile = new File("19138.ttf");
Font myFont;
{
    try {
        myFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,fontFile);
    } catch (FontFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Выдаёт исключение:

```
java.io.IOException: Can't read 19138.ttf
 at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:1054)
 at com.pumaex.GameField.<init>(GameField.java:58)
 at com.pumaex.LinesLauncher.main(LinesLauncher.java:5)
```

Т.е. получается, что программа не может прочитать файл. Но почему?

Что я написал не так?

Comment: либо нет прав на чтение файла, либо нет самого файла

Comment: Файл лежит в папке с программой.

Comment: Я не пользовался maven. Неужели чтобы просто загрузить шрифт он необходим?

Comment: getResourceAsStream помог. Не пойму, а почему мой метод не работал?

Comment: @pumaex слишком мало информации для ответа. Непонятна структура вашей программы, способ компиляции и способ запуска.