# Jar файл выдаёт исключение

Tags: java, swing, шрифты

Класс GameField

```
private Font myFont0;
{
    try {
        myFont0 = (Font) StaticMethods.loadFile("ARIALN.ttf");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FontFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

метод loadFile() для загрузки класс StaticMethods

```
public static Font loadFile(String filePath) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, FontFormatException {
    try (final ObjectInputStream myObjectFile = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(GameField.class
            .getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath)))) {
        return Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, myObjectFile);
    } catch (FontFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему не получается использовать шрифт?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138283/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82)

Comment: Возможно, поможет [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/765248/204271).

Answer (score 0):

ваш шрифт должен лежать в папке ресурсов. попробуйте использовать такой метод:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class GameField {

    public static Font loadFile(String filePath) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, FontFormatException {
        try (final InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(GameField.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath))) {
            return Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Font font = loadFile("assets/fonts/ARIALN.ttf");
        Font myFont1 = font.deriveFont(30f);
        System.out.println(myFont1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109101/discussion-on-answer-by--jar---).

Comment: Запустил ваш файл, всё работает. Не пойму в чём проблема

Comment: @pumaex  код корректный, это точно. что делаете вы и почему у вас не работает, сложно сказать. тут телепатия нужна)) сбрасывайте свой исходный код. можете удалить все лишнее, класса, выполняющего чтение, и класса, который к нему обращается , достаточно.

Comment: Проблема в том, что я загружаю ВАШ код. Запускаю - всё работает. Делаю джарик - не работает. Видимо я неправильно делаю jar-файл. Но делаю как написано и до сих пор всё работало. Графические файлы в своей программе загружаются без проблем. Чем они отличаются от файлов шрифтов не понимаю

Comment: @pumaex так может у вас файл-шрифта некорректный? мой не пробовали взять?

Comment: Я взял этот шрифт у себя в системе - это Arial. К тому же в IDE всё работает. Вот это вообще необъяснимо. Работа застопорилась. Не знаю, что делать

Comment: @pumaex давайте исходный код с указанными классами, других вариантов я не вижу

Comment: Дело в том, что ВАША тестовая программа(которая записана в вашем ответе) чуть выше нормально работает в IDE. Но как только я из неё делаю jar-файл получаю исключение - Stream closed.     Я теперь думаю, может быть это у меня IntelliJIdea глючит? Может такое быть? Сейчас хочу попробовать сделать jar-файл на Eclipse. Не знаю сколько придётся с ним разбираться, ни разу до этого не пробовал